# How to prove Linear Independence

Tags: linear-algebra

How to prove the set $S=\{x,|x|\}$ is linearly independent. Where S is a subset of set of real valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

Thank You.

Comment: Please vote on and select answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two non-zero vectors in a vector space are linearly dependent if one is multiple of he other. Do you think that you can find a constant $c$ such that $cx=\mid x\mid$ for all $x$?

Comment: If $x>0$ then $c=1$ and if $x<0$ then $c=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the definition of linear independence: do there exists constants $c_1,c_2$, not both zero, such that $c_1x+c_2|x|=0$?

If so, they are linearly dependent. If not, they are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

If $c_1 x + c_2 |x| = 0$, for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$, then $c_1 (1) + c_2|1| = 0 \implies c_1 = -c_2$, and substituting in $x=-1$ we have $c_1 = c_2$.  The only simultaneous solution to
$$
c_1 + c_2 = 0, \\
-c_1 + c_2 = 0
$$
is $c_1 = c_2 = 0$, so yes they're linearly independent.